# How to take snapshot in linux - programmatically C++

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am currently involved in a project which requires me to repeatedly take snapshots of the screen. I am using qt's grabScreen function to do the same.
The screen freezes for half a second every time the program takes a snapshot causing the computer to seem to be very slow :(

Can anybody suggest me a better method of doing this ?

Comment: +1 It seems like most screenshot utilities take a second or two (even Imagemagick and other more specialized programs). In Windows, the Win32 API offers a function for this. Surely X11 has something?

Comment: thats comforting ... it would be great if you could point be in the direction where I could find it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at the source of, say, `ksnapshot` which is the Qt-based KDE app doing this. Its SVN archive is [here](http://websvn.kde.org/trunk/KDE/kdegraphics/ksnapshot/).

Comment: I have seen the source code of ksnapshot and have also gone through the code of an example screenshot program on trolltech's website (http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/desktop-screenshot.html), both of  which use basically the same function. And I am even using that very function ( without the gui interface - I don't need the interface right now )

Answer (score 3):

If you're OK with doing it in lower level manner, then you should look into one of those xorg tools that I can't remember the name of. It's installed by default and outputs the screenshot in a bitmap format. It's a shame I can't remember the name.

EDIT: I got it! It's "xwd". Cheers.