# How to serve an image of the screen as an input to a program, in Haskell

Tags: graphics, haskell, screenshot

I'd like to write a function (I'm using Haskell) that's capable of retrieving the actual content of the screen, as viewed by the user, in order to pre-elaborate (grayscaling and/or some stencil convolution through the repa package) and feed it to a neural network or some other AI architecture.

The type would be something like watch :: IO img
Is there a library that provides functions like this? And if I needed not the entire screen but only the visual output of a program, is there other way than hand-cutting the image?

Answer (score 5):

Grabbing the screen is platform dependant. And you'll need to find a C library that does this, then write a Haskell binding to that low level functionality. On some systems you may be able to open the frame buffer as a file as grab the image.

So, the answer is the [same as for C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814347/how-to-take-snapshot-in-linux-programmatically-c), but you write a binding from Haskell to that function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a look at the source code of **scrot**